# How to programmatically focus to a node in PrimeNG Tree?

Tags: angular, primeng

Using PrimeNG, I can scroll to a TreeNode:

In html:

```
<p-tree #mytreeid id="mytree"></p-tree>
```

In Angular:

```
@ViewChild("mytree") mytree: Tree;
// selection is the TreeNode you want to scroll into view
scrollToSelectionPrimeNgDataTree(selection, tree, elementIdName) {
      if (tree.value !== null) {
          let index = tree.value.indexOf(selection);
              let ele = document.getElementById(elementIdName).querySelectorAll("p-treenode")[index];
              ele.scrollIntoView();
              //ele.focus();
      }
  }
```

Question: How to make the TreeNode(ie. 'selection') focused? I tried to call the focus() method, but focus() is not the method of the Element.

Comment: Actually what I want is the TreeNode can have a attribute, like [selected], when it is set to 'true', the Tree will scroll to the node and focus on it, ie. the node is 'selected'.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, we only need to set the [(selection)] to the selected node:

```html
<p-tree #mytree id="mytree" [value]="componentGroups" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedNode">
```

Answer (score 0):

You must transform your previous data to TreeNode and bind it to the selection property
the below would be a good candidate as an example:
assume that you have a list of nested categories and you are supposed to select one of them in edit mode:

```
previouslySelectedParentCategory:TreeNode

initializeForEdit(){
 this.previouslySelectedParentCategory= 
    this.convertCategoryToNode(this.selectedParentCategory)
}


  private convertCategoryToNode(category): TreeNode {
    return {
      key: category.categoryId,
      label: category.name,
      data: category,
    };
  }
```

HTML file

```
 <p-tree
        [filter]="true"
        [value]="categoriesNode"
        [scrollHeight]="defaultScrollHeight"
        selectionMode="single"
        [(selection)]="previouslySelectedParentCategory"
        display="chip"
        (onNodeSelect)="handleNodeSelect($event)"
        #parentCategoryTree
      >
        <ng-template p-Template="empty">
          {{ "primeng.emptyMessage" | translate }}
        </ng-template>
      </p-tree>
```